# Rails: Test module defined by default in all modules but actually... not really

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, dynamic-programming

If I do the following in irb:

```
module Useless ; end

Useless.const_defined? 'Test'
```

It obviously returns

```
=> false
```

But when I do the same in any of my rails apps console, the answer is:

```
=> true
```

My first guess was that I was somehow conflicting with a test framework. I was wondering which one and it became strange when I noticed that even if "true" was returned, it seemed to be nevertheless undefined ...

```
irb(main):004:0> Useless::Test
NameError: uninitialized constant Useless::Test
    from (irb):4
    from /home/laurent/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@nanoscripts/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /home/laurent/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@nanoscripts/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /home/laurent/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@nanoscripts/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Does someone have an explanation for this ?

Of course I know I should avoid to name a module "Test", but the point is that I am generating dynamically some classes and modules into a module that I use as kind of name space from database introspection. Therefore nothing prevents a table to be named test (this is how I discovered the thing) which would trigger the creation of a class named:

```
MyNameSpaceForDynamicallyCreatedObjectsFromDatabase::Test
```

Basically what should I do ?

- Hardcode something for test ? and then is there an exhaustive list of table names I should hardcode something for ?
- Is there another way to determine if a constant is present in a module without interfering with whatever underlying mechanism I am conflicting with ?

Any help appreciated.
Rgds

Comment: I don't understand. The error is correct, there is no such Constant: `NameError: uninitialized constant Useless::Test`. You are safe to go. Anything to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to work around by doing a `constants.include? 'Test'.to_sym` instead of `const_defined?`:

```
module Useless ; end

Useless.constants.include? 'Test'.to_sym
```

Correctly returns the expected:

```
=> false
```

And this both in raw ruby and in rails.

The only drawback being that constants returns an array of symbols.
This solves my problem but doesn't explain the why of this `const_defined?` behaviour.